# stop ng repeat from makeing recursive call to tab ui select event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, recursion

I have problem, when i create angualrjs tabs ui dynamically, the ng repeat will keep call select event function recursive and Pass county IDs and Call the Web API to get data. just want to ask for solution to stop ng repeat from passing county IDs and make API call?
View

```
    <tabset>
<tab ng-repeat="tab in countytabs" heading="{{tab.countyName}}" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
    <h3>{{tab.countyName}}--{{tab.phoneNumber}} </h3>
    <tabset>
        <tab heading="All" active="active.all" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
            <br />
            <span>Total:{{totalStatusforByCounty.total}}, In:{{totalStatusforByCounty.in}}, Out:{{totalStatusforByCounty.out}}, Unknown: {{totalStatusforByCounty.unknown}} at {{totalStatusforByCounty.lastUpdatedDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}} </span>
            <br />
            <div ng-repeat="groupUsers in allUserByCounty">
                <h6>
                    <b>{{groupUsers.title}}</b>
                </h6>
                <table ng-repeat="user in groupUsers.users">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} Ext:{{user.voiceMailExt}} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </tab>
        <tab ng-repeat="departmentGroup in departmentGroups" heading="{{departmentGroup.name}}" select="selectAllUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(tab.countyID,departmentGroup.id)">
            {{departmentGroup.name}}<br />
            {{tab.countyID}}<br />
            {{departmentGroup.id}}<br />

            <div>
                <p>
                    <span>
                        Total:{{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.total}}, In:{{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.in}}, Out:{{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.out}}, Unknown: {{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.unknown}} at {{totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup.lastUpdatedDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy 'at' h:mma"}}
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>

            <div ng-repeat="groupUsers in allUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup">
                <h6>
                    <b>{{groupUsers.title}}</b>
                </h6>
                <table ng-repeat="user in groupUsers.users">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}} Ext:{{user.voiceMailExt}} </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </tab>
    </tabset>
</tab>
</tabset>
</div>
```

javascript

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('usersboard');

    var ReceptionController = function($scope, ReceptionService){

        $scope.countytabs = '';
        $scope.totalStatusforAllCounties ='';
        $scope.totalStatusforByCounty = '';
        $scope.departmentGroups = '';
        $scope.totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = '';
        $scope.allUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = '';
        $scope.allUserByCounty = '';
        $scope.AllUserInAllDepartmentGroupsGroupByCounties = '';
        $scope.AllUsersInDepartmentGroup= '';
        $scope.active = {
            all: false
        };
        $scope.content = 'county';
        $scope.isShown = function (content) {
            return content === $scope.content;
        };

        var selectAllCounties = function(){
            ReceptionService.selectAllCounties().then(function(data){
                $scope.countytabs = data;

            }, function(errMsg){
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        selectAllCounties();

        var selectTotalStatusforAllCounties = function(){
            ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforAllCounties().then(function(data){
                $scope.totalStatusforAllCounties = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, function(errMsg){
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        selectTotalStatusforAllCounties();

        var selectAllDepartmentGroups = function(){
            ReceptionService.selectAllDepartmentGroups().then(function (data) {
                $scope.departmentGroups = data;
                console.log(data);
            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        selectAllDepartmentGroups();

        $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty = function (id) {
            if (typeof id !== 'undefined'){
                ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(id).then(function (data) {
                    $scope.totalStatusforByCounty = data;
                    console.log($scope.totalStatusforByCounty);
                }, function (errMsg) {
                    console.log(errMsg);
                });
            }

        }
        $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = function (countyId, departmentGroup) {
            ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(countyId, departmentGroup).then(function (data) {
                $scope.totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = data;
                console.log($scope.totalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup);
            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        $scope.selectAllUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = function (countyId, departmentGroup){
            $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(countyId, departmentGroup);
            ReceptionService.selectAllUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup(countyId, departmentGroup).then(function (data) {
                $scope.allUserByCountyAndDepartmentGroup = data;

            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        $scope.selectAllUserByCounty = function (countyId) {

                $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(countyId);
                ReceptionService.selectAllUserByCounty(countyId).then(function(data){
                    $scope.allUserByCounty = data;


                }, function(errMsg){
                    console.log(errMsg);
                });

        }

        $scope.selectAllUserInAllDepartmentGroups = function () {

            ReceptionService.selectAllUserInAllDepartmentGroups().then(function (data) {
                $scope.AllUserInAllDepartmentGroupsGroupByCounties = data;

            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }
        $scope.selectAllUsersInDepartmentGroups = function (departmentGroupId) {

            ReceptionService.selectAllUsersInDepartmentGroup(departmentGroupId).then(function (data) {
                $scope.AllUsersInDepartmentGroup = data;

            }, function (errMsg) {
                console.log(errMsg);
            });
        }


    };

    app.controller('ReceptionController', ['$scope', 'ReceptionService', '$window', ReceptionController]);

}());
```

Comment: can you give more info?

Comment: could you please create a plunkr/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, please elaborate more if this does not meet your requirement.

But if your problem is recursive API Call with parameter CountyId, look at one your select expression:

```
...line 83
$scope.selectAllUserByCounty = function(countyId) {
  $scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(countyId);
  ReceptionService.selectAllUserByCounty(countyId).then(...
```

that method above will call `$scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty()` which as you can see from your code line 48, it will also trigger another API request using your `ReceptionService`.

```
...line 48
$scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty = function(id) {
  if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {
    ReceptionService.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(id).then(...
```

But since you do not provide the question with what are you trying to achieve, i assume that you did that recursive call using countyId parameter on purpose. Totally fine eventhough there's a better way to serve singleton data using `angular.service` so you don't have to always call the API if the data has ever been requested and all you need to do is to make it persist in the Angular Application.

But also, as you see in your HTML code:

```
<tab ng-repeat="tab in countytabs" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
    ...
    <tabset>
      <tab heading="All" select="selectAllUserByCounty(tab.countyID)">
      ...
```

If you read the documentation on https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs, the expression you defined in the `select=""` attribute will always be triggered whenever you switch between tab. This probably also means the `select=""` expression nested under the ng-repeat will also be triggered if its spesific parent tab is activated since it will also activate its children tab.

This is also why you will run a recursive hell calling the `$scope.selectTotalStatusforByCounty(id)` which triggered so many `ReceptionService.selectAllUserByCounty(countyId)` API call whenever you switch between county tab, or even in initiating this html page.

The solution is definitely not having `selectAllUserByCounty()` as your `select=""` expression in the nested ng-repeat on the second level or more, because the first level of `ng-repeat` tab has already done it for the whole children tabs.

Or even better, try to change the pattern on how do you want to serve the data collection in the Angular Application runtime, such as creating service singleton or sacrificing the first API call to actually load everything in the initial page load and only matter of switching between `(countyID)` inside the persistent object whenever the `select=""` expression is triggered so you don't have to do API call everytime you switch the tab.

Let me know if i didn't make myself clear by commenting below.